# <canvas> width and height breack just on IE11

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, canvas

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="300" height="300" style="position:absolute; top:100px;left:215px; border:1px solid red"></canvas>

var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
```

this works fine on all browser and even IE but stop working on IE 11

is there any thing I should add or play arround to make it working?

Comment: You could start with posting the exact error message you see in the browsers error console.

Comment: there is no error message.. my chart just get bigger and bigger every time I click

Comment: That seems quite bizarre behavior to me. I would rather suspect a bug in your code. Please try to reproduce the bug in [SSCCE-form](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: <canvas id="myChart" width="300" height="300" style="position:absolute; top:100px;left:215px; border:1px solid red"></canvas>\

Comment: that was my canvas and var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");

Comment: @UIDeveloper please show your click handling code! (in the question, not here in the comments)